# File Upload Progress Event not firing, although file uploads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, jquery-events

I've seen a few posts on here with similar issues, but I can't seem to get this solved. Basically, I have an AJAX file uploader that doesn't seem to call the progress event. The other events fire just fine, and the file uploads exactly as I expect it, but the progress event isn't being called. The Javascript is shown below:

```
$('input[name=avatar_upload]').change(function(e) {
    // Get the Form
    var setupForm = $('#setup-member-form');

    // Get the File Array
    var file = document.getElementById('avatar-upload').files[0];

    // Show the File Upload Progress
    $('#avatar-upload-progress').show();

    // Create a new Form Data Object
    var formData = new FormData();

    // Add the File
    formData.append('avatar', file);

    // Create the AJAX Object
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Add the Event Listeners
    ajax.addEventListener("loadstart", function(evt) {
         // Do something in here...
         $('#output').append("upload starting...\n");
    }, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
         var percentLoaded = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
         $('#output').append(percentLoaded + "% loaded\n");
         $('#avatar-upload-progress .ui-progress-bar-inner').animate({'width' : percentLoaded + '%'}, 400);
    }, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
         // Do something in here when loaded...
         $('#output').append("upload complete!");
    }, false);

    // Open the Form
    ajax.open("POST", $('input[name=upload_handler]').val());
    ajax.send(formData);
});
```

At first I thought it might just be because the file was too small for the progress event to have a chance to fire, but I've tried it with larger files, and the load event fires, then there is a few seconds pause, then the complete event fires.

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tested this, and for uploads you have to use `XMLHttpRequest.upload`, as attaching the events directly to `XMLHttpRequest` only fires once when uploading.

It's also explained in the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress)

```
$('#avatar-upload').on('change', function () {
    var file = document.getElementById('avatar-upload').files[0];

    $('#avatar-upload-progress').show();
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('avatar', file);

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajax.upload.addEventListener("loadstart", function (evt) {
        $('#output').append("upload starting...\n");
    }, false);

    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
        var percentLoaded = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
        $('#output').append(percentLoaded + "% loaded\n");
        $('#avatar-upload-progress .ui-progress-bar-inner').animate({
            'width': percentLoaded + '%'
        }, 400);
    }, false);

    ajax.upload.addEventListener("load", function (evt) {
        $('#output').append("upload complete!");
    }, false);

    ajax.open("POST", $('input[name=upload_handler]').val());
    ajax.send(formData);
});
```

Comment: In my case I am using XMLHttpRequest.upload but it's still not firing.  Only if I force the debugger to stop by putting the word "debugger;" in my script, then it will fire, but otherwise it just blows right past.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the way I was creating the XMLHttpRequest object.  Turns out I was missing the "window" object.  I had this:

```
requestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
requestObject.upload.addEventListener('progress', videoUploadProgress, false);
```

And changed it to this:

```
requestObject = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
requestObject.upload.addEventListener('progress', videoUploadProgress, false);
```

Now it works.